# Adding and removing rows from sql server table when making updates to record

Tags: asp.net, t-sql, c#-4.0, sql-server-2014

I have a SQL Server table that contains two columns AppID and GroupID. The table is populated from a asp listbox. An AppID can have many GroupID's associated with it.

It works fine for adding Groups for each App and when a user wants to edit a record I can populate the Listbox with the already selected items.

What I want to know is when a user edits the items in the listbox, they can deselect existing items and select new ones what is the best way to update the table in the database? Would I be better to delete all the records for the AppID or is there a better way?

There isnt likely to be more than 12 Groups linked to anyone App.

**EDIT**

Sorry should have said that the table is a link table between the Apps table and the Groups table. The IDs in the link table are the primary keys from those tables.

TIA

Comment: The best way is to normalize your table. The `GroupId` belongs into another table `AppGroups` which has the `AppId` as foreign-key. If the user removes a group from the `ListBox` an entry in this table has to be deleted. Into the `App`-table  belong only informations that are relevant for the app. Groups are a different topic and the relation belong into a related table.

Answer (score 0):

Pro grammatically it would be easier to delete everything for the AppID and add them all back in. However your performance would take a huge hit using this method.

So your best method from a performance perspective would be to split the operation into 2 parts:

- find records in your link table that are no longer in your ListBox &
  delete them
- find records in your ListBox that aren't in the table & insert them

This will only work well if you keep track of the data to insert and delete as the user clicks on the ListBox. Then apply the changes all together as doing the inserts & deletes one record at a time would mean many more transactions which would be slower.

---

EDIT

A further performance improvement would be to turn some of the deletes & inserts into updates as updates are typically faster than delete + insert. Albeit this would add complexity to your code so it comes down to what is more important.

1. As before keep track of the deletes & inserts as the user makes changes to the ListBox
2. Count how many deletes & inserts you have
3. Take the lowest number and that is how many delete + inserts you can convert into an update. For example, if you need to delete GroupID 123 & insert GroupID 456, then instead just update GroupID 123 to 456.
4. If you have left over deletes, then perform those, otherwise handle the leftover inserts